# Match two files with duplicate ids in awk or sed

Tags: awk

I have two files. File 1 has 3000 rows (1500 Ids) and File 2 has 1400 rows (700 Ids). File 1 contains all the ids present in file 2. I have to match the ID column of File1 & File 2 while maintaining the order of the ids. If the id from file 2 is present in file 1 then compare column 2 and print match or mismatch. catch is there are duplicate ids and i need to keep them all. Looking for a awk or sed solution.Thanks!

```
File1
ID  A
1   13
1   14
2   13
2   13
3   13
3   12
4   13
4   14
5   14
5   14

File 2
ID A
2 13
2 13    
3 13
3 3
5 14
5 15



Desired output
ID A
2 13 Match
2 13 Match    
3 13 Match
3 3 mismatch
5 14 Match
5 15 mismatch
```

Comment: Why is `5 14 mismatch` shown in the output? '5 14' did appear in File 1

Comment: In file 1 Value for first occurrence of 5 is 14 where as for first occurrence of 5 in file 2 value is not 14 (it is 15), thus a mismatch. So first occurrence of id in file 1 is to be matched with first occurrence of same id in file 2 and second occurrence of id in file 1 is to be matched with 2nd occurrence of id in file 2

Comment: does the posted answer meet your requirement. you should give some feed back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `awk` to achieve that,

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{ if(a[$1]=="") a[$1]=$2; next}
  /[0-9]/{
    if(a[$1]==$2){
      print $0,"match"
    } else {
      print $0,"mismatch"
    } id=$1
}' File1 File2
```

Output:

```
2 13 match
2 13 match
3 13 match
3 3 mismatch
5 14 match
5 15 mismatch
```

Brief explanation,

1. `NR==FNR{...}`: in File1, save id/value to array `a` if the id has never shown previously
2. `if(a[$1]==$2)`: if the id and value match in File2, view the record as match, and mismatch otherwise.

Comment: i ran it as sh my. awk file1 file 2 but it keeps running and gives no output

Comment: @akang, the answer should work fine, I tried it without problem here. you may go to check your script if some problems in it.

Comment: Thanks I got it runnng! But there is some problem with the if statement if(id!=$1 && a[$1]==$2). It shows "mismatch" at some places even where there is a match.

Comment: @akang Can you show the case out, or modify it in the questions, so that I can get more information.

Comment: Basically if there are two consecutive matches it shows one as a mismatch.

Comment: You mean if another `3   13` showed in your File1 & File2?

Comment: Ok, I modify my answer as well.

Comment: @akang, if the answer can fix your problem, please kindly set the check to accept the answer. :)

Comment: That doesn't do the job as I see some "matches" which are actually "mismatches" and vice versa. One id occurs twice in both the files , could you please explain how you are matching the those ids?

Comment: @akang You should list all the requirement at the first time rather than make further request after the answer has been offered. The answer for your question work fine. You need to consider all conditions carefully before you issue the question.

Comment: You are right, i should have been careful while posting the question! I'll keep it in mind the next time. I figured out the mistake. Your code works fine. Mistake was in the input. Many thanks for your cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to traverse the rows in File 2 and for each row find the matching ID in file 1. As you do not provide a programming language, here is the solution in pseudocode:

```
for all rows in file2
  for all rows in file1
    if current_row_file1.id = current_row_file2.id
    then
      if current_row_file1.value_column2 = current_row_file2.value_column2
      then
        print current_row_file2.id + current_row_file2.value_column2 + "Match"
      else
        print current_row_file2.id + current_row_file2.value_column2 + "Mismatch
```

The code above takes some time as you loop through all records in file 1 for every row in file 2. If your ID's in file 1 are ordered you can use an algorithm like binary search to speed up the processing. Look here for an explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm